# pgadmin4 not displaying properly

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've installed PostgreSql, pgadmin4 came along with it first. It didn't work so I installed the latest version of pgadmin4 v4 again but still its the same. It was showing a fatal error message earlier which said "Failed to open the system default web browser. Is one installed?." After that, it somehow worked & it started in my IE when I set it as my default browser. I tried opening it in Firefox too setting it as default browser but the result was same.

It shows the following screen rather than the expected normal screen that should appear as soon as we start it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the issue, use the Windows Registry Editor to reset the value of

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.css\Content Type

to

> text/css

and then restart pgAdmin4.

Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#6

Note: Use Chrome or Firefox latest version with pgAdmin4, IE11 does not support many latest HTML technologies, for example with IE11 you will not able to download the graphical explain plan.